# what time should the association set for this criterion?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am trying to solve questions about distributions. However, I have problems with them. So,

> For the boys in a secondary school, the time to run a mile distance is
>   approximately normally distributed with a mean of 450 seconds and a
>   standard deviation of 40 seconds. If a physical fitness association
>   wants to designate the fastest 10% as "excellent" what time should the
>   association set for this criterion?

I know that $N(450, 40^2)$ 
but I don't know how to calculate or how to answer to this question

Comment: Did the anser help ?

Comment: @callculus I didn't get how did u find 1.28 ?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Let $T$ be the random variable that denotes the time to run a mile by a random student.

Then you know how $T$ is distributed (normally), so can you tell me what $$P(T\leq 420)$$ is?

Comment: where did you get 420 ?

Comment: @WhoAmI I just want to see if you can answer this question. The way you answer it will tell you alot about how to solve the full question. If you answer it, I can provide further hints.

Comment: Maybe a more helpful 'instructional problem' would have been to evaluate $P(T \le 500) \approx 0.89.$ Maybe your approach was not immediately obvious to OP, but at least you're trying to teach, not just do someone's hwk.(+1).

Answer (score 1):

You can standardized the  variable. Let $X$ be the random variable of  time to run a mile. Then X is normally distributed as $\mathcal N(450,40)$. Then $Z=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}=\frac{X-450}{40}$ where Z is distributed as $\mathcal N(0,1)$ The fastest $10\%$ are the $10\%$ above the $90\%$.

Thus the question is  $P(X\leq x)=\Phi\left(\frac{x-450}{40} \right)\geq 1-0.1=0.9$

$\Phi(z)$ is the cdf of the standard normal distribution.

Taking the inverse.

$\frac{x-450}{40} \geq \Phi^{-1}(0.9)$

Looking at a [table](http://math.arizona.edu/~rsims/ma464/standardnormaltable.pdf) of the standard normal distribution it can be seen that $\Phi^{-1}(0.9)$ is approximately $1.28$ The equation becomes

$\frac{x-450}{40} \geq 1.28$

Finally solve for $x$.

Comment: why 1.28 ?  not .46017 ?

Comment: @WhoAmI I don´t know why do you get this value. You have to look at which value of $z$ the probability is $0.1$. So you look (inside the table) for a value which is close to $0.1$ This is iin the row of $z=1.2$ ( first decimal place). and then in the 9-th comlumn of this row. $\Phi(-1.28)=0.10027 \approx 0.1$

Comment: Makes no sense. Looking for _fastest._ Please check: In R, `qnorm(.9, 450, 40)` returns 501.2621.

Comment: @BruceET Ouch, that´s embarrassing. I misread the question like the lowest 10%. I have corrected my answer. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: As champion 'misreader of questions', I look forward to a similar cautionary note from you soon.

Answer (score 1):

**Comment.** It is often helpful to make a sketch for problems such as this. Here are two. At left below, is a sketch based on $Norm(\mu=450, \sigma=40);$ at right
is a sketch based on standard normal, which is relevant if you are using printed tables instead of software. Your job is to find the positions of the vertical red lines that cut off the upper 10% of the area under each density curve.

[image]

My favorite way to show the work for such a problem is as follows:

$$.9 = P(X \le x_0) = P\left(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} \le \frac{x_o - 450}{40}\right)
= P\left(Z \le \frac{x_o - 450}{40} = z_0 \right).$$
Look for the entry in the body of a standard normal table that is closest to .9000 and
then look at its margins to find $z_0$ (correct to two places). Finally, solve   $\frac{x_o - 450}{40} = z_0$ for the desired answer $x_0.$